# How do I select this section in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to select a range of cells based on the values of choice, but I can't figure out how to fix it to select these cells. Could I get some help. I need to select the cells in the range based on the number of cells there are after the rest of the macro runs. This macro separates specific cells based on how many empty cells are before n.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub emptysinder()
    Dim g As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Dim num As Integer
    
'    Rows("1:1").Select
'    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
'    Range("A1").Select
'    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
'    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:BA1"), Type:=xlFillDefault
'    Range("A1:BA1").Select
'    Range("AQ10").Select
'    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 25
'    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 24
'    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 23
'    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 22
'    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 20
'    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 15
'    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1

    
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        
    For g = 1 To 9
        Set r = Range("F1").Offset(0, g - 1).Resize(200, 1)
        If IsAllEmpty(r) Then
            num = num + 1
            Debug.Print "Range " & r.Address & " is all empty." & num
        ElseIf IsAnyEmpty(r) Then
            Debug.Print "Range " & r.Address & " is partially empty."
        Else
            Debug.Print "Range " & r.Address & " filled."
        End If
        
    Next g
    split (num)
    tToT (num)
End Sub
Public Function IsAllEmpty(ByVal r_range As Range) As Boolean
    Dim Item As Range
    For Each Item In r_range
        If Not IsEmpty(Item) Then
            IsAllEmpty = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    IsAllEmpty = True
End Function
Public Function IsAnyEmpty(ByVal r_range As Range) As Boolean
    Dim Item As Range
    For Each Item In r_range
        If IsEmpty(Item) Then
            IsAnyEmpty = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    IsAnyEmpty = False
End Function
Public Function split(i As Integer)
    Dim sheet As Integer
    Dim colOpt As Integer
    sheet = 15
    Dim partialSheet As Integer
    partialSheet = sheet - 6 - i
    colOpt = sheet - i
    Dim s As Integer
    Do While partialSheet > 0
        Columns(colOpt).Select
        i = i - 1
        colOpt = colOpt - 1
        
        Selection.Insert
        Selection.Insert
        Selection.Insert
        Selection.Insert

    partialSheet = partialSheet - 1

    Loop
        
End Function
Public Function tToT(i As Integer)
    Dim sheet As Integer
    Dim part As Integer
    Dim choice As Range
    sheet = 15
    part = sheet - i
    choice.Select
    
    
End Function
```

Comment: What's your end goal? Selecting cells cannot be it.

Comment: text to column on them so i can split them up by -

Comment: If you only have 200 rows, a loop with `split` would be far easier.

Comment: how would i do that

Comment: [`split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function)

Comment: doesnt work for putting each in new columns

Comment: You write the array back to cells.... Edit: how do you think text to columns work?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting different cells can be done as follows:

```
Range("F3:G3,G4").Select
```

This consists of:

- Selecting a single cell:

  ```
    Range("G4").Select
  ```
- Selecting a rectangle of cells: (select, using <kbd>Shift</kbd> button)

  ```
    Range("F3:G3").Select
  ```
- Selecting a list of random cells: (select, using <kbd>Control</kbd> button)

  ```
    Range("F3:G3,G4").Select
  ```